# Why write $\mathrm dx, \mathrm dt$ etc. at the beginning of an integral?

Tags: integration, notation

I've noticed that many people here (on Math.SE) as well as elsewhere write integrals out like this:

$$\int^a_b \mathrm dt \; f(t)$$

instead of the more common (at least from what I've seen):
$$\int^a_b f(t) \; \mathrm dt$$

Some quantum mechanics books I've seen also do the same (put the $\mathrm dt$ in front.)

Are there any practical reasons for this?

Comment: I always thought it was to look nicer, especially when you have a lot of variables.

Comment: It is a new fashion, imported, as you point out, from Physics. There is a mild argument in favour for iterated integrals.